# I want to loop a prompt and save each loop in an array

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I want to create a program that loops a prompt(input) but to a limit specifically four times and saves each looped prompt to an array.
This is my code

```
const fruits = [];
var ask = prompt('Enter a fruit');
for(let num = 0; num < 5; num++){
fruits.push(ask); } console.log(fruits);
```

```js
const fruits = [];

var ask = prompt('Enter a fruit');

for(let num = 0; num < 5; num++){
    fruits.push(ask);   
}
console.log(fruits);
```

But this is the result
[
"Banana",
"Banana",
"Banana",
"Banana",
"Banana"
]

It only asks for the input once and saves it in the array five times, any ideas?

Comment: You can just put the `prompt` call inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move prompt inside the loop so that you ask question each time.

```js
const fruits = [];

for(let num = 0; num < 5; num++){
    var ask = prompt('Enter a fruit');
    fruits.push(ask);   
}
console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

The prompt is responsible for taking input and need to be shown 4 time, so it should also be inside the loop

```js
const fruits = [];

   

for(let num = 0; num < 5; num++){
    var ask = prompt('Enter a fruit'); // put here
    fruits.push(ask);   
}
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: But it's not inside the loop in your response.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi left by mistake

Answer (score 1):

prompt should be inside the loop and if you want to loop 4 times then for loop should look like this. try this.

const fruits = [];

```
for(var num = 0; num < 4; num++){
    fruits.push(prompt('Enter a fruit')); 
}
```

console.log(fruits);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a one-liner (or just prefer a functional approach) you can do this:

```
const fruits = [1,2,3,4,5].map(() => prompt('Enter a fruit'));
```